# CSS : stencil effect

Tags: css, mask

**I wonder if it is possible in pure css to have a stencil effect:**
A block with a background color, and color "transparent" that would reveal the background of the parent block.

**For example,** I have a parent block with a gradient or pattern as background, and I want to overlay a block with a black background where the text content would leave see the gradient of the parent block.

I haven't found a way to get this to work, but maybe someone has an idea or a tip?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I should not be precise enough.

Here is a picture of the desired result:
[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to post a picture of what you have in mind.

Comment: Are you referring to CSS masks? Like this http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/?

Comment: Based on your edited post, couldn't you just make a png of the "T" and set the opacity via CSS?

Comment: Wouldn't the transparent T just allow the `background-color` of the element in which it's sitting be shown? I don't think this is possible, without relying on SVG.

Answer (score 4):

May be you can use CSS3 **background-clip**. write like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>T</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:impact;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-h-c-1414-1431-2.jpg); 
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
position:relative;    
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
}
p:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
body{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-h-c-1414-1431-2.jpg); 
}
```

​

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rD6wq/6/

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.

But unfortunately this only works
1 - for webkit
2 - if the background image of the parent (body) is superposed with  background of the child block (<p>). This gets complicated if there are several children : [http://jsfiddle.net/rD6wq/](http://jsfiddle.net/rD6wq/)

Comment: you can give position-attachment:fixed to the background check this  http://jsfiddle.net/rD6wq/1/

Comment: But only for Webkit… And I have found no draft at the W3C concerning a future standard ??

Comment: There is very nice example of it at CSSTricks: http://css-tricks.com/animated-knockout-letters/

Answer (score 1):

Something using an embedded font, such as http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Allerta+Stencil may be close to what you want.  By changing the background and text colours, you should get what you are looking for

Comment: Perhaps your idea of a 'stencil effect' and my idea of a 'stencil font' are different..!

Answer (score 1):

```
#element_id {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

this will set the opacity of the div or whatever you apply it too 40% of its original opacity (which is usually 100% unless you apply this to .png or .gif images with reduced opacity already)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use SVG for that, but it won't be trivial.

[This](http://my.opera.com/dstorey/blog/using-svg-masks-for-cut-out-text-effects) (and [this](http://dev.opera.com/static/dstorey/images/newyorkmaskexample.svg)) might be the closest implementation of what you need. The problem is that it doesn't work the same in every browser, though you may try deeper research.

**Upd**: Lea Verou has presented a simple and elegant solution in her article: [Text masking — The standards way](http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/#more-1721)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the CSS3 `text-shadow` property.

```
p{ text-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 }
```

See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/ZCUrV/1/).

Detailed info about the property [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textshadow.html).

Comment: You might want to use `color: rgba(255,255,255,0);` for the text then.